# Cannot boot to Ubuntu after Windows 7 installation and "boot-repair" does not work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, boot-repair

I hope someone here can help me:
I re-installed my Windows 7 partition and now I cannot boot to Ubuntu 14.04 any more - no grub boot-menu is display instead directly the "Loading windows" screen is shown.

If I go to the boot menu in BIOS I can select my Ubuntu - drive and boot from it (which is quite cumbersome).

So I tried to use "boot-repair" as described at at the help pages but the program exits with an error.

This is the link I get from "boot-repair": http://paste.ubuntu.com/7558812/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction - here is the fix for the problem:

1. Start via Live-CD
2. Mount Linux partition
3. ```
   $ sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/ubuntu/e2eec732-eb12-47e4-8c4d-5f50d4ad5986/ /dev/sdb"
   ```
4. Restart
5. In BIOS change boot priority of devices - prio 1 is Linux
6. Fixed - grub is loaded first and the Windows can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into the install disk and type in `sudo grub-update /dev/sda`  (open gparted though to make sure you have the right disk, if the Ubuntu partition is mounted somewhere else then type in the Mount point instead of `/dev/sda/` as it could be something like sdab or /media/sda .

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple and works for me

Insert Ubuntu cd and select try Ubuntu, connect to Internet. Open terminal ( Ctrl+Alt+T ),

Login as root:

```
sudo -i
```

Find out your linux disk :

```
fdisk -l
```

Mount it:

```
mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

Recover:

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```